# VBA Performance issue calling several subs within a main sub

Tags: vba, excel

I have a Module with several Subs in it. Something like this:

```
    Sub Main()

    Call ReadData      '12 seconds
    Call SortData      '8 seconds
    Call RemoveDupes   '30 seconds

    End Sub
```

This Main Sub is called from a Userform and takes 2m to run in total. However if I call the subs individually I get the times shown in the code above.

After much testing I realized the problem occurs when calling the last sub. It goes from 30 seconds to about 1m40s for no apparent reason. I comment the third call on the Main Sub and when it ends I call it manually, directly from the VBA Editor window and goes back to 30s.

Are there any reason why such a thing can happen?

Thank you very much in advance!

PS: The individual codes from each sub are a little lenghty so I didn't post them, but they're very straight forward nothing complicated at all. I'm using Excel 2010 btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VBA cleans up a lot of "loose ends" when it completes running a VBA program / macro. For one thing, it returns any memory used by the program. If you comment out the call to RemoveDupes, the program will end after sortData, and this clean up process will take place. Then you run RemoveDupes manually, using a clean slate.

Check to see if in the first two subs, you create many/large collections or other objects that don't get set to Nothing at the end of the sub. I think they would have to be declared in the top of the module, before the code for any Sub or Function.

Comment: Thanks Rich, that's exactly what happens. I declared a few public variables but I use them on the first subs not the last one. I'll work on that.

Comment: I dont know why this answer was marked down, but Rich is right on. Improper variable cleanup can go a long way to slowing down code (especially in the case of objects). To take it one step further, you can make variable cleanup a bit easier by storing them all in a collection and then looping through the collection to clean them up (only if you have many, dont do this for just a few). Also, if you are reading data from multiple workbooks, be sure to close the workbook once you have the data. This will make things a bit better as well.